# Disable a repository and remove all the software installed from it

Tags: centos6, repository

I have a CentOS box where I installed an external repository and added some software, mostly java related.

Now I want to get back to the initial repository (only CentOS Base) and remove all the software installed from it. Is there anyway I can *easily* do this ? I already know how to remove a repository but this will not remove the installed software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before you remove the repository:

```
yum list installed | grep [reponame]
```

Be aware, however, that this will only show packages which were most recently installed by the repository in question. If the package was updated with a version from another repository, it will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM:

> Want to query all those packages installed from 3rd party repositories, not CentOS?
>
> rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} %{VENDOR}\n' | grep -v CentOS

Change that to grep for the repo you want to get rid of, that way you get a list of all the packages.
Then loop over that list and remove them.
I don't know of any easier way.